# Chain instantiation of php classes

Tags: php

I have three  php classes. I can instantiate them this way:

```
$piza = new Mashrooms(new SeaFood(new PlainPiza()));
```

However when I try to instantiate them dynamically in this way:

```
$temp = Mashrooms(new SeaFood(new PlainPiza())); 
$piza = new $temp;
```

it fails and shows this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'SeaFood(new Mashrooms' not found.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: And why do you need to do that?

Comment: That's just not the syntax in PHP for instantiating objects...

Comment: I am using decorator design pattern. I want the user to choose a topping and calculate the price accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`$temp` is an Object, not a Class, and you cannot use the `new` keyword on an existing Object.

```
$plain = 'PlainPiza';
$seafood = 'SeaFood';
$mashrooms = 'Mashrooms';

$piza = new $mashrooms(new $seafood(new $plain)));
```

Given the new information

> The problem is I don't know how many classes I will instantiate

I think your approach my be wrong. Have you thought about having a Pizza class and adding your topping objects to the pizza object? For instance:

```
<?php

class Pizza
{
    private $_toppings;
    private $_placements = array('left', 'right', 'whole');

    public function _construct()
    {
        foreach($this->_placements as $placement)
        {
            $this->_toppings[$placement] = array();
        }
    }

    public function add_topping(Base_Topping $topping, $placement)
    {
        if(in_array($placement, $this->_placements))
        {
            array_push($this->_toppings[$placement], $topping);
        }
    }
}

abstract class Base_Topping
{
    protected $_price = 0.00;
    protected $_name = 'No Name';

    public function get_name()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function get_price()
    {
        return $this->_price;
    }
}

class Mushrooms extends Base_Topping
{
    protected $_price = '1.00';
    protected $_name = 'Mushrooms';
}

// assuming $_POST['toppings'] = array('Mushrooms' => 'whole', 'Pepperoni' => 0, 'Sausage' => 0, etc...)
$pizza = new Pizza();
$toppings = array_filter($_POST); // will return anything with a non-false value
foreach($toppings as $name => $coverage)
{
    $topping = new $name();
    $pizza->add_topping($topping, $coverage);
}

?>
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many classes I will instantiate. It depends how toppings user selects.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$temp = "Mashrooms";
$pizza = new $temp(new SeaFood(new PlainPiza()));
```

See here: http://3v4l.org/RXDLX